# JOIN single table flink tableapi by two columns

Tags: sql, scala, join, apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a table with data and I need to make a join by two fields.

I wrote a request, but it does not work

```
SELECT * 
FROM Data t1 
JOIN Data t2 ON t1.s = t2.o
```

the code is

```
val csvTableSource = CsvTableSource
  .builder
  .path("src/main/resources/data.dat")
  .field("s", Types.STRING)
  .field("p", Types.STRING)
  .field("o", Types.STRING)
  .field("TIMESTAMP", Types.STRING)
  .fieldDelimiter(",")
  .ignoreFirstLine
  .ignoreParseErrors
  .commentPrefix("%")
  .build()
tableEnv.registerTableSource("Data", csvTableSource)

val query = "SELECT * FROM Data t1 JOIN Data t2 ON t1.s = t2.o"
val table = tableEnv.sqlQuery(query)
```

I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Cannot generate a valid execution plan for the given query: 

FlinkLogicalJoin(condition=[=($0, $6)], joinType=[inner])
  FlinkLogicalTableSourceScan(table=[[Data]], fields=[s, p, o, TIMESTAMP], source=[CsvTableSource(read fields: s, p, o, TIMESTAMP)])
  FlinkLogicalTableSourceScan(table=[[Data]], fields=[s, p, o, TIMESTAMP], source=[CsvTableSource(read fields: s, p, o, TIMESTAMP)])

This exception indicates that the query uses an unsupported SQL feature.
Please check the documentation for the set of currently supported SQL features.
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can show us your entire example. Including how you embedded the SQL and your sink.

Comment: @twalthr, I added the exception in the question

Comment: Which Flink version are you using?

Comment: @FabianHueske 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you are trying to run this query in a streaming environment.
Non-windowed joins on streaming tables were added with Flink 1.5.0.

So you are trying to use a feature that is not supported in Flink 1.4.2 yet.

You can either switch to a batch environment which should be possible given that you are reading CSV files or upgrade to Flink 1.5.0.

Comment: After updating, I have Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: STRING here .field("s", Types.STRING). What is the problem?

Comment: Cleaning maven did not help

Comment: I don't know. Maybe the API of the `CsvTableSource` changed. However, this error is not related to the original question of missing support for `JOIN`. Feel free to open a new question or reach out to the Flink mailing list.

Comment: I deleted .m2 folder, reimported the project and now it works. Thank you!